# Network Discovery tool - java

Tags: java, networking, eclipse-plugin, snmp, discovery

I need to write a network discovery eclipse plugin, to fetch OS details, what architecture (32/64) given a subnet or ip range, and present a topology view.

Appreciate any help / pointers on how to get started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I worked for startup company that implemented something like this during 4 years and was acquired by VERY big company for a lot of million USD. So, good luck!

But seriously you cannot fetch all needed data using pure java only. Some things require using native tools.

You can take a look on [JPcap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/) for passive discovery that will allow you to catch some packets from network and probably parse them to extract topology information. 
You can use [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to connect to Unix machines using SSH. [Apache Commons-Net library](http://commons.apache.org/net/) will help you to connect to computers using telnet.

Comment: One sentence is relevant : "You can take a look on JPcap for passive discovery that will allow you to catch some packets from network and probably parse them to extract topology information." All the rest is useless. "VERY big company" is not know-how.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to use a lower level language. I don't think Java will be able to accomplish all your requirements.